# Running a service when email arrives

Tags: windows, email, service, download, exchange-server

I'm creating an application that downloads an attachment from an email that's automatically generated at midnight every night. The attachment is downloaded into a directory and from there is then parsed into a database.

The main problem with this is that the email generation takes time, so the actually delivery time is unknown. Instead of having a program running the entire time, waiting on it to arrive, it would be far more elegant to have it automatically run the service to download the attachment when the email drops in the inbox, much in the same way as a FileSystemWatcher works on local directories.

The email server runs Exchange 2003

Is there a way, programmatically or otherwise, to cause a service to run on receiving a new email?

Comment: What application receives the email? If its just an email server, you could see what extensibility features it supports

Comment: @AlexK. it's just an email server, running Exchange 2003

Answer (score 0):

Exchange has the ability to run event sinks when certain things occur on the server.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324021 shows an example of doing this to create a catchall email address.

Details of the exchange 2003 SDK are at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms986138(v=exchg.65).aspx